# Easy bind many JavaFX properties to UI-Nodes

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I work on an Application which asks a SQL-Database for different values. Here i have one table nearly 40 Columns and my pojos have JavaFX-Properties. So now i bind this properties which are filled with data from the database to the UI-Components like textfields, etc.

The way i do it right now is to manually bind all the ui properties to the pojo properties. But this is one big method with 40 entries to manually bind all the properties.

Can you tell me a better way to do this? Maybe like the table system of javafx to bind the properties by string?

@James_D: Thanks for your response. My idea was to extend the textfields and so on with an string value which i set in fxml and this string = the name of the propertie to bind. That´s nearly like the mapping system of javafx tables.

@kelopatra: I dont want to populate tables with values. I allready have a system for this. What i want is to automate the binding process between my ui and my pojo. For example:

This is my pojo which gets filled with values form database:

```
public class SimplePojo {

private final StringProperty button_propertie = new SimpleStringProperty();
private final StringProperty lable_propertie = new SimpleStringProperty();

public SimplePojo(String button, String lable){
    this.button_propertie.setValue(button);
    this.lable_propertie.setValue(lable);
}

public String getLable_propertie() {
    return lable_propertie.get();
}

public void setLable_propertie(String value) {
    lable_propertie.set(value);
}

public StringProperty lable_propertieProperty() {
    return lable_propertie;
}

public String getButton_propertie() {
    return button_propertie.get();
}

public void setButton_propertie(String value) {
    button_propertie.set(value);
}

public StringProperty button_propertieProperty() {
    return button_propertie;
}
```

This is my Controlle to display the values to the user:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private Button button;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    //Getting result from Database
    SimplePojo sp = new SimplePojo("label_text", "button_text");
    //Bind properties to ui elements
    doBindings(sp);
}    

public void doBindings(SimplePojo sp){
    this.button.textProperty().bindBidirectional(sp.button_propertieProperty());
    this.label.textProperty().bindBidirectional(sp.lable_propertieProperty());
    //If i have 50 fields in pojo ... this would not end ....
}
```

And here in the controller is the problem ... look at the comment in "doBindings" ... this list would nearly not end!

Comment: Using any standard approach, you should just have one line of code for each of the properties/controls. It's hard to see how you could reduce this to less than that, since somewhere you must specify which control maps to which property.

Comment: can you show a small example? Don't quite understand what you mean: you can certainly automate the creation of the columns, assuming you have a list of something like "meta-data" for those. But can't imagine how you would want to use that for other controls ..

Comment: Are you trying to automate the creation of your user interface?  That is not a good idea;  you’ll just end up with a lousy user interface.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, got it :)

Comment: No, not the automation of my ui but with the automatic assignment of properties in pojos to ui fields so i dont have to manually type 100< of lines of code ...

Comment: There's no simple solution. The bottom line is that if you have 50 properties in your model and a control for each, you're going to have a lot of code. (You actually have ~10 lines of code in the model for each property, plus at least one line of code in the FXML file; only one more line in the controller doesn't seem like a big deal, really.) Your idea of subclassing the controls is viable, but note that 1. if you pass a `String`, you would need reflection to do the binding; it's probably better to pass the property itself; 2. you need to subclass each control (button, label, etc).

Comment: If the controls are not editing controls (e.g. the label and button in the example code will not have their text changes by the user), then you can just use [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) directly in the FXML. For text fields, for example, that won't work.

Comment: @James_D interesting how "real" (aka: bidi) bindings are not supported - not being a big fan of fxml, that's what might make me sway ;) AFAIR (it's been a while) good ol' SwingLabs binding had exactly that: a configurable correlation between data bean properties and form properties ...

Comment: @kleopatra Yes... I suppose they do support "nested properties" (`"${controller.bean.value}"`), which makes setting the property vaguely problematic (at which step of the chain do you want something to be changed?). But, yeah; supporting bidi bindings in some reasonable subset of use cases would be a lot more appealing.

Comment: found the planning stage to include: http://fxexperience.com/2011/10/fxml-why-it-rocks-and-the-next-phase/ but not when it was dropped ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. So in conclusion we can say, that it is not possible to automate the process of binding properties to UI-elements and it has to be done manually. There is a plan to support bidirectional bindings in FXML in the future. Link from kleopatra: http://fxexperience.com/2011/10/fxml-why-it-rocks-and-the-next-phase/

Comment: You did realize that this was written almost 7 years ago?

Comment: hmm ... maybe my comment was misleading: there had been plans to support bidi-binding in 2011 (there even had been starters of an implementation that some daring devs used), but the plan was silently (or not so silently, no idea) dropped along with the internal implementation sometime around fx2.2 or so .. didn't follow. So currently there's no hope for the future, I think (@mipa also)